# Polylogarithmic value-bounded concurrent data structures such as max register, counter, and monotone circuit

Tags: reference-request, data-structures, distributed-systems, concurrency

While reading the research paper [Polylogarithmic Concurrent Data Structures from Monotone Circuits [@JACM'2012]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2108244) by James Aspnes, Hagit Attiya, and Keren Censor-Hillel, I am not sure about some points and need some verification and explanation.

In the first three sections of the paper, the authors presents constructions of useful concurrent data structures, including **max register** and **counters** with bounded values, with step complexity that is *polylogarithmic* in the number of values the object can take or the number of operations applied to it. Specifically (and extremely in brief),

> The max register is an object $r$ supporting both `WriteMax(r,t)` and `ReadMax(r)` operations. It is recursively constructed from a tree of increasingly large max registers. The implementation is wait-free and linearizable.
>
> The counter, supporting an `CounterIncrement()` operation and a `ReadCounter()` operation, is structured as a binary tree of max registers. The implementation is also wait-free and linearizable.

My problems are as follows:

> (1) **On the max register:** What is the space complexity, i.e., the number of base objects of multi-writer multi-reader (MWMR, for short) registers, of the recursive implementation?

[[**In my opinion:**]] It is $2m - 1$ for there is exactly one MWMR register for each node in the tree. In particular, the tree can be thought of as the logic structure of an underlying array of $2m-1$ MWMR registers.

> (2) **Also on the max register:** Is it possible to implement a max register with only a single MWMR register? Are there any related work?

[[**(EDIT) In my opinion:**]] I have found a [related paper: Time and Space Lower Bounds for Non-blocking Implementations [@PODC'1996]](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~satcc112/wiki.files/Jayanti-Time-and-Space-Lower-Bounds.pdf), in which Jayanti et al. show that

> Operations must take $\Omega(n)$ **space** and $\Omega(n)$ steps in the worst case, for many common data structures, including (unbounded) max registers and (unbounded) counters, where $n$ is the number of concurrent processes.

However, I have not realized similar conclusions concerning about value-bounded data structures.

> (3) **On both the max register and the counter:** Are there any related work on the max&min register supporting both `ReadMax(r)` and `ReadMin(r)`? Similarly, are there any related work on the inc&dec counter supporting both `CounterIncrement()` and `CounterDecrement()`?